# Can I convert any number of minutes before or after midnight to time of day in decimal form using trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry

I currently have a programming challenge where I have to convert any number of minutes before or after midnight (`midnight = 0`) into a 24-hour formatted time.

My thought process was to first convert the minutes into a decimal format and then into the 24 hour format.

However, I am a bit stuck on the first part due to the fact that any number can be chosen even if it is outside the 24-hour limit (`1440 minutes`).

For example:

`3000 = 02:00`

`-1437 = 00:03`

I tried to set up a cosine equation so I could follow the 24-hour cycle with the following parameters.

Max Y = 24

Min Y = 0

Period = 2880   (two days)

K = (2PI)/2880

d = 12

a = 12

c = 0

The equation then becomes the following:

`y = a(-cos(k(x-c)))+d`
or
`y = 12(-cos(2PI/2880(x)))+12`

`IF x / 1440 is odd, THEN y = |y - 24|`

I have NO idea if I am doing this right or if this is even allowed in mathematics.
I just remember trig functions and the unit circle being important with time and cycles so I tried it out.

Am I on the right track or should I completely scrap this and start over?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What makes you think that you'd need trigonometric functions? Just take the modulus (remainder) of the numbers. Let's take a silly example, a random number like 529340 minutes. How many hours is that?
$$
\frac{529340}{60} = 8~822.333... ~\text{hours}
$$
Take the integer part of that, that makes $8~822$ hours. If you want to know what the clock says about that, take the reminder with 24 to get
$$
MOD(8~822, 24) = 14
$$
So that's two o'clock in the afternoon. Great. Now the minutes:
$$
MOD(529340, 60) = 20
$$
So answer: 14h20. It's that easy.

Comment: Thank you! I'd figure the right/standard answer had something to do with taking remainders and converting those into minutes. 

I guess my overarching question is, Is this another potentially creative way to solve this problem given that Trig functions are used when thinking about cycles? Or can trigometric functions not fundamentally operate in this way?